# How to prevent Django's label_tag function from escaping the label?

Tags: python, django

Example:

```
>>> example.label
&#x3bb;<sub>blabla</sub>
>>> example.label_tag()
[...]&amp;#x3bb;&lt;blabla&gt;[...]
```

Even calling `mark_safe(example.label)` before `label_tag()` does not prevent Django from escaping the HTML. How can I get `label_tag()` to return unescaped labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a comment in the [code for `label_tag`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2ced2f785d5aca0354abf5841d5449b7a49509dc/django/forms/boundfield.py#L135)

```
Wraps the given contents in a <label>, if the field has an ID attribute.
contents should be 'mark_safe'd to avoid HTML escaping. If contents
aren't given, uses the field's HTML-escaped label.
```

So

```
example.label_tag(contents=mark_safe(example.label))
```

Should work.. I can't see another way around this problem

Comment: And you'll need 
**from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

            h = HTMLParser()
            unescaped = h.unescape(example.label_tag())
            print unescaped
```

Comment: This might solve the problem at hand, but it's not an answer to my question. Is there no way to just keep label_tag from escaping?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark the label as safe when you define the field.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    example = forms.Field(label=mark_safe('&#x3bb;<sub>blabla</sub>'))
```

Example:

```
>>> f = MyForm({'example': 'foo'})
>>> str(f)
'<tr><th><label for="id_example">&#x3bb;<sub>blabla</sub>:</label></th><td><input id="id_example" name="example" type="text" value="foo" /></td></tr>'
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the application I'm working with. It's a pretty big codebase; presumably the label is used somewhere else in the application and the "safe" tag is removed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, glad you found a solution that works for you. I'm going to leave the answer posted, hoping it help someone else in the future.